# slide and reveal sibling over another sibling element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to slide a sibling element (yellow) over another sibling element (red) making sure that the yellow never slides over the blue elements, only the red, but I am having a lot of issues with z-indexes. Is there a way to achieve this without z-index maybe? And is it possible to have multiple yellow and red elements in different positions where the yellow element always slides over the red element?

See my progress here, currently the yellow slides over the blue element: **https://jsfiddle.net/0qf95eap/25/**

**JS:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var slideToLeft = $('.yellow');

  slideToLeft.show();
  slideToLeft.css('z-index','5');
  slideToLeft.prev().css('z-index','1');
  slideToLeft.next().css('z-index','1');
  slideToLeft.nextUntil(".row").css('z-index','10');

  slideToLeft.animate({right: "25%"}, 2000);

  slideToLeft.prevUntil(".row").css('z-index','5');
  slideToLeft.animate({right: "50%"}, 2000);

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li class="blue row"></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="red"></li>
  <li class="yellow"></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="blue row"></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="blue "></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="blue row"></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.previous {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3 !important;
}
.next {
  z-index: 9;
}
```

Comment: if z index is not set the lowest element in the code should always over lap. so if the code is like <div>div1</div><div>div2</div> then, baring an other set styles, if div2 is modved into the same space as div1 then div2 will cover the first div. so if you can ensure all yellow's are above lower in the dom tree then all blues, but higher than all yellows, then the z index is unneeded.  as for with javascript, I don't know jquery but in raw js you can set a z index using element.style.zindex= '2'. I don't know if this helps any but good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var elements = $('.yellow');
  for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
  {
    $(elements[i]).show().css('z-index','50').animate({left: "-100%"}, 2000);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  z-index:100;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="blue row"></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="red"><div class="yellow">
  </div></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="red"><div class="yellow">
  </div></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="blue "></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="blue row"></li>
  <li class="red"><div class="yellow">
  </div></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Amazing! This is it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set `z-index` in the CSS and only for the blue elements.

- blue needs to be on top of red and yellow. `z-index:1` + `position:relative` can be set
- yellow needs to be on top of red. `position:absolute` + being next, it will do itself (defaut z-index is 0 ).
- red do not need a `z-index` and can skip the `position:relative;` to avoid bringing it at top.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var slideToLeft = $('.yellow');
  slideToLeft.show();
  slideToLeft.animate({right: "25%"}, 2000);
  slideToLeft.animate({right: "50%"}, 2000);

});
```

```css
* {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  list-style:none;
}
li {
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.previous {
}
.next {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="blue row"></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="red"></li>
  <li class="yellow"></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="blue row"></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="blue "></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="blue row"></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0qf95eap/76/